# What's an accurate term for "technical terminology" in the sentence:

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

> I am a sucker for "knowing the exact term for a phenomena, a process, etc in a technical environment".

Jargon is probably not a good word since it's too casual, and probably disapproving.

Comment: Is it specifically for a technical environment, or does it also need to serve other contexts such as legal, medical, military, etc?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus? There are at least 40 words that are synonyms to "jargon". Some of them actually fit your need.

Answer (score 4):

nomenclature

It describes a set or system of names or terms. As in the particular science or art's correct names.

Comment: no need whatsoever to comment on, or answer, questions that should just be clicked closed

Answer (score 2):

I would go with *terminology*, as you said. Or *vocabulary*.

> **Terminology**: n. The body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, theory, profession, etc.
>
> **Vocabulary**: n. Words used on a particular occasion or in a particular sphere

- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/terminology)
- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vocabulary)

*Lingo* would also work, although it is also colloquial and not as formal.

> **Lingo**: n. The vocabulary or jargon of a particular subject or group of
> people

- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lingo)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [lexicon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lexicon) in this place to refer to what you're calling an "environment".

> Lexicon (noun):
>
> 2. the vocabulary of a particular language, field, social class, person, etc.

That, in my opinion, is a better fit than "jargon", which commonly connotes the confounding elements of a certain group's vocabulary.

Comment: This is it. I was looking for this particular word. Nomenclature is too technical, I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like ***"nomenclature"*** for this purpose, which is very close in definition to "Terminology":

Per definition 3a in [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nomenclature):

> ***Nomenclature***: 3a:  a system or set of terms or symbols especially in a particular science, discipline, or art

Example: **"A directory and nomenclature of the first aeroplanes, 1809 to 1909"** - Charles Harvard Gibbs-Smith, Science Museum (Great Britain)
H.M.S.O., 1966

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "precise technical term" or "precise technical definition".

```
What is the precise technical definition of hard real-time?
```

*Precise*, because that conveys the idea a bit better than *exact*.

*Technical*, because you don't want the dictionary definition, but rather the current technical usage.